# two threads sharing same array java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads, A and B. A has to create messages and store them in a list in memory and B has to read the first message from the same list in memory, remove it from the list and do something with it.

A and B start with a main thread.

My question is how can I make a list that is shared by two different threads?

Comment: pass reference to other thread :)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html. Create an instance of this queue, and pass it as argument to the constructor of both runnables. And there you are: they share the queue. Note that multi-threadig is an advanced, very complex subject. If you have to ask this question, it's a sign that it's probably too early for you to start working on that subject.

Comment: Look into using a lock/semaphore

Comment: Pass that list (thread-safe implementation) to both threads. For example as constructor arguments for your `Thread` or `Runnable` objects

Comment: You may also want to do some research into the "producer/consumer" pattern

Comment: Tip: study the book [*Java Concurrency In Practice*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127932.Java_Concurrency_in_Practice) by Goetz.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-solution-using-threads-java/

And the Java sample they have there should help with some modifications for your scenario.

```
// Java program to implement solution of producer 
// consumer problem. 
import java.util.LinkedList; 

public class Threadexample 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
                        throws InterruptedException 
    { 
        // Object of a class that has both produce() 
        // and consume() methods 
        final PC pc = new PC(); 

        // Create producer thread 
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        { 
            @Override
            public void run() 
            { 
                try
                { 
                    pc.produce(); 
                } 
                catch(InterruptedException e) 
                { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        }); 

        // Create consumer thread 
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() 
        { 
            @Override
            public void run() 
            { 
                try
                { 
                    pc.consume(); 
                } 
                catch(InterruptedException e) 
                { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        }); 

        // Start both threads 
        t1.start(); 
        t2.start(); 

        // t1 finishes before t2 
        t1.join(); 
        t2.join(); 
    } 

    // This class has a list, producer (adds items to list 
    // and consumber (removes items). 
    public static class PC 
    { 
        // Create a list shared by producer and consumer 
        // Size of list is 2. 
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>(); 
        int capacity = 2; 

        // Function called by producer thread 
        public void produce() throws InterruptedException 
        { 
            int value = 0; 
            while (true) 
            { 
                synchronized (this) 
                { 
                    // producer thread waits while list 
                    // is full 
                    while (list.size()==capacity) 
                        wait(); 

                    System.out.println("Producer produced-"
                                                  + value); 

                    // to insert the jobs in the list 
                    list.add(value++); 

                    // notifies the consumer thread that 
                    // now it can start consuming 
                    notify(); 

                    // makes the working of program easier 
                    // to  understand 
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        // Function called by consumer thread 
        public void consume() throws InterruptedException 
        { 
            while (true) 
            { 
                synchronized (this) 
                { 
                    // consumer thread waits while list 
                    // is empty 
                    while (list.size()==0) 
                        wait(); 

                    //to retrive the ifrst job in the list 
                    int val = list.removeFirst(); 

                    System.out.println("Consumer consumed-"
                                                    + val); 

                    // Wake up producer thread 
                    notify(); 

                    // and sleep 
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

As others have advised, I think you should spend some time understanding threading and producer consumer pattern.

Answer (score 1):

First create an instance of the list.

Second pass the list as argument to the constructor of both runnables.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    List<MyType> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    Runnable r1 = new MyRunnable(myList);
    Runnable r2 = new MyRunnable(myList);
    new Thread(r1).start();
    new Thread(r2).start();
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    List list;

    public MyRunnable(List list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {}
}
```